# How to format a multi-line statement with a label

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am trying to format a multi-line statement with a label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Let $P(n)$ denote the statement that
\begin{equation}
\text{The sum of the natural numbers less than or equal to $n$ is given by the formula }
0 + 1 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\tag{P(n)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Unfortunately, the statement overflows the right margin.
I don't think using the `align`, `multline` or the `gather` environments would be suitable because the horizontal alignment would not be correct.
How should I format the mathematical statement?

**Things I would like:**

- I would like the statement to be indented as in the `quote` environment.
- I want the label to be "P(n)" rather than "(P(n))" as is currently in the output

Comment: Use `\tag*` instead of `\tag` to realise labels without parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is text, so it should be treated as such:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

Let $P(n)$ denote the statement that
\[
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
The sum of the natural numbers less than or equal to $n$ is given by the formula
$0 + 1 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
\end{minipage}
\tag{$P(n)$}
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `\tag*{$P(n)$}` (note math mode, in any case), you get the tag without parentheses:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `gathered` environment inside of the `equation` environment, as in

```
Let $P(n)$ denote the statement that
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    \text{The sum of the natural numbers less than or equal to $n$}\\
      \text{is given by the formula $0 + 1 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.}
  \end{gathered}
  \tag*{P(n)}
\end{equation}
```

[image]